# Are there any SyncML server components that work in .NET?

Tags: .net, mobile, synchronization, syncml

Basically we'd want to create a SyncML server that we can hookup to our own custom data source, all the component would do is listen for client connections and notify and request  data from our code return the data back to the client.  Looking primarily to sync Contact data from our app with various mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

[SyncML.NET is at SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/syncmldotnet/), but I've personally never tried it.

Comment: That's a SyncML client, what we're looking for is a SyncML server component that we can integrate into our application

Answer (score 0):

You can try **[Compelson SyncML server](http://syncml.mobiledit.com)** from [Compelson labs](http://compelson.com). It has an SDK for custom Storage. By default it ships with SqlServer data store for sync clients. The SDK also has a sample project which uses File System as data store for sync clients.

Chk this link: **http://www.mobiledit.com/downloads.asp?show=syncml_developers**